# Sending message to MSMQ via java client

Tags: java, msmq, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using MSMQ to send message from java client using eclipse IDE. I have followed instructions from the link:

http://msmqjava.codeplex.com/releases/view/42708.

In its source code it has a java class `TestClient.java` by which I am able to delete , create and open queue successfully.

When I try to send or receive message from the queue it gives me following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ionic.Msmq.Queue.nativeSendBytes([BLjava/lang/String;[BIZ)I`

please help!!

Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: Hi I haven't got any response on this . please reply it will really help me !!

Comment: I'm able to run it successfully, can you paste the full error? or Just try sending message to an already created Queue?